# How add ECR and Dynamodb permission in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr

I already have the ElasticBeanstalk (Multicontainer) template. In addition to that, I want to get Docker image from ECR which I already have `****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/traveltouch:latest` in my ECR repo. (If want to create new repo also fine). I mentioned that image in my `Dockerrun.json` and Dynamodb also needed. Here how to attach that permission and add My ECR repo and new dynamodb table into to my  `MyInstanceProfile` and the `cloudformation`.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  sampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application
  sampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: !Sub "elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-182107200133"
        S3Key: TravelTouch/Dockerrun.aws.json
  sampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MinSize
        Value: '2'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MaxSize
        Value: '6'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: LoadBalanced
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
        Value: !Ref MyInstanceProfile        
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.26.0 running Multi-container Docker 19.03.13-ce (Generic)
  sampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment
      TemplateName:
        Ref: sampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: sampleApplicationVersion
  MyInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Description: Beanstalk EC2 role
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
  MyInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles:
        - !Ref MyInstanceRole
```

and my `Dockerrun.json`

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "environment": [{
      "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
      "value": "admin"
    },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
        "value": "postgres"
      },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
        "value": "traveldb"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "image": "postgres:12-alpine",
    "memory": 300,
    "mountPoints": [{
      "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
      "sourceVolume": "postgres_data"
    }],
    "name": "db",
    "portMappings": [{
      "containerPort": 5432,
      "hostPort": 5432
    }]
  },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "name": "web",
      "image": "****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/traveltouch:latest",
      "memory": 300,
      "portMappings": [{
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [{
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
    },
    "name": "postgres_data"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I want to add ECR into my already existed cloudformation. Like I want to create new ECR repo and new Dynamodb along with the already existed cloud formation